# Hall effect in superconductors

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, superconductivity

In many papers on Hall effect in superconductors (in the mixed state), experimental results are plotted as magnetic field vs Hall angle. Why we need to consider the Hall angle in these cases? Can't we simply see the variation of Hall coefficient with field. Why is Hall angle so important in this case?